# How to Gstreamer's udpsrc display (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, gstreamer, gstreamer-sharp

I would like to use gstreamer to display udpsrc video, but it does not work.
On the command line it works fine.
"Gst.Video.Global.IsVideoOverlayPrepareWindowHandleMessage(msg)" will always be False.
Please help me...

send command:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe autovideosrc ! videoconvert ! vp8enc deadline=1 ! rtpvp8pay pt=96 ! udpsink port=5200 host=<MY-LOCALIP> async=false
```

recv command:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe udpsrc port=5200 caps="application/x-rtp,payload=(int)96" ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=10 ! rtpvp8depay ! avdec_vp8 output-corrupt=false ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

csharp program:

```
private void CreatePipeLine()
{
        if(pipeline != null)
        {
            pipeline.SetState(State.Null);
            islive = false;
            return;
        }
    
        pipeline = new Pipeline("pipeline");//"playback");
    
        var udpsrc = Gst.ElementFactory.Make("udpsrc", "source");
        udpsrc["port"] = 5200;
        //udpsrc["caps"] = "application/x-rtp,payload=96";
    
        var jitter = Gst.ElementFactory.Make("rtpjitterbuffer", "jitter");
        jitter["latency"] = 10;
    
        var depay = Gst.ElementFactory.Make("rtpvp8depay", "depay");
        var avdec = Gst.ElementFactory.Make("avdec_vp8", "avdec");
        avdec["output-corrupt"] = false;
    
        var convert = Gst.ElementFactory.Make("videoconvert", "convert");
    
        var capsRTP = Gst.Global.CapsFromString("application/x-rtp,payload=96");
        var mAppSink = new AppSink("appsink");
        mAppSink["emit-signals"] = true;
        mAppSink["caps"] = capsRTP;
        mAppSink.NewSample += OnNewSample;
    
        ink = Gst.ElementFactory.Make("autovideosink", "ink");
    
        pipeline.Add(udpsrc, jitter, depay, avdec, convert, mAppSink); //ink);
    
             
        udpsrc.Link(jitter);
        jitter.Link(depay);
        depay.Link(avdec);
        avdec.Link(convert);
        convert.Link(ink);
    
        Bus bus = pipeline.Bus;
        bus.AddSignalWatch();
        bus.Message += OnBusMessage;
    
        bus.EnableSyncMessageEmission();
        bus.SyncMessage += new SyncMessageHandler(OnBusSynMessage);
    
        /*
        VideoSink = new AppSink(ink.Handle);
        VideoSink.Drop = true;
        VideoSink.MaxLateness = (1000 / 30) * 1000000;
        VideoSink.MaxBuffers = 1;
        VideoSink.Qos = true;
        VideoSink.EnableLastSample = false;
        VideoSink.Caps = Gst.Caps.FromString("video/x-raw,format=RGBA");
    
        pipeline.Bus.EnableSyncMessageEmission();
        pipeline.Bus.AddSignalWatch();
        pipeline.Bus.SyncMessage += OnBusSynMessage;
        pipeline.Bus.Message += OnBusMessage;
        */
    
        pipeline.SetState(State.Null);
        var ret = pipeline.SetState(State.Ready);
}
```

```
private void OnBusSynMessage(object o, SyncMessageArgs sargs)
{
    Gst.Message msg = sargs.Message;
    if (!Gst.Video.Global.IsVideoOverlayPrepareWindowHandleMessage(msg)) { return;}

    Element src = msg.Src as Element;
    if(src == null) { return;}
    try { src["force-aspect-ration"] = true;}
    catch(PropertyNotFoundException) {  }

    Element overlay = ((Gst.Bin)src).GetByInterface(VideoOverlayAdapter.GType);
    if(overlay == null) 
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Overlay is null");
        return;
    }

    _adapter = new VideoOverlayAdapter(overlay.Handle);
    _adapter.WindowHandle = _windowHandle;
    _adapter.HandleEvents(true);
    _isRender = true;

}
```

Tried this method during playback, but "sample" was null.

```
var sink = VideoSink;
if(sink == null) { return; }

Sample sample = sink.TryPullSample(5000);
if(sample == null) 
{
    return; 
}
```

Reference Site:
https://github.com/vladkol/gstreamer-netcore/tree/master/samples/AvaloniaPlayer
[how to use application/x-rtp binding with gstreamer-sharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43939871/how-to-use-application-x-rtp-binding-with-gstreamer-sharp)

I've changed the caps location to udpsrc,
I have tried autovideosink, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Gst.Video.Global.IsVideoOverlayPrepareWindowHandleMessage(msg)

will be not null only if you have autovideosink in your pipeline. This is because a Window creation request will be created if you have Window "VideoSink" like autovideosink, glvideosink... which implements GstVideoOverlay. (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/opengl/glimagesink.html?gi-language=c#hierarchy see implemented interfaces)

`pipeline.Add(udpsrc, jitter, depay, avdec, convert, ink);`

Why not setting your pipeline to playing instead of ready ?

```
    var ret = pipeline.SetState(State.Playing);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I was able to get out of "IsVideoOverlayPrepareWindowHandleMessage" by making it "glvideosink ".
The final goal is to process image data, but "sink.TryPullSample" is still null.
Do you know the cause?
(Pressing the playback button executes "pipeline.SetState(State.Playing)".)

Change
    ink = Gst.ElementFactory.Make("glimagesink", "ink");
    VideoSink = new AppSink(ink.Handle);